# Тает память при простой прокрутке ListView

Tags: android, android-sdk, listview, memory

Обычный ListView, Адаптер:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

final static public String TAG = "MyAdapter";

Application application;

// ...

private HashMap<Integer, View> views = new HashMap<>();

private final Context context;

public ConnectionsAgentAdapter(Context context)
{
    super(context, R.layout.menu_item);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (views.containsKey(position)) {
        return views.get(position);
    }

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.agent_connections_list_item, null, true);

    // ...

    views.put(position, rowView);
    return rowView;
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position)
{
    return false;
}
```

При простой прокрутке начинает хавать память. По идее все поместил в views и новые обьекты создаваться не могут... Memory Analyzer выдает вот такой результат:

[image: Memory Analyzer]

Подскажите как понять этот вывод, правда и так понятно что память тянет ListView. Как это можно исправить и почему так может происходить? Дело в том что я по всему приложению встречаю такие утечки (там где их просто не может быть).

Comment: дак ты же в hashmap вьюшки складываешь
views.put(position, rowView);  при прокрутке создаются новые вьюшки с складываются. Их даже сборщик мусора не удалит, потому что у тебя ссылки на них запомнены, даже когда вьюшки уже давно нет на экране.

Comment: там проверка в самом верху. views.containsKey(position)

Comment: дак и что эта проверка дает ? будет у тебя там 1000 позиций в списке, у тебя будет в памяти болтаться 1000 вьюшек и никогда не удалятся.

Comment: Велосипед с HashMap заменить на ViewHolder pattern - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance

Comment: Суть в том что память течет, а новые вьюшки даже не создаются.

Comment: в общем смотри в сторону convertView http://android-er.blogspot.ru/2010/06/using-convertview-in-getview-to-make.html
полюбому у тебя проблема в HashMap, вьюшка должна строится по данным, а не хранится вся в памяти, причем converView тебе позволит ограничится только теми viewками корые видны и не создавать лишних.

Comment: Вопрос же про память. Куда она может деваться?

Comment: Ну дак у тебя она в HashMap и утекает  :))) мы тебе про память и отвечаем :) Т.е. мало того, что у тебя view создается каждый раз при getView, это само по себе плохо, потому что создаются лишние вьюшки при прокрутке списка, но ты еще их и сохраняешь в hashmap, что делает невозможным для сборщика мусора их удаление :)

Comment: полюбому у тебя проблема в HashMap - нет без HashMap таже история. Я предположил что течет при постройки вьюхи и для теста заблочил HashMap-ом а ситуация не изменилась...

Comment: И можно вообще из Memory Analyzer что то разобрать? :)

Comment: Ну ты сделай нормально по паттерну ViewHolder, если будет утекать - то значит проблема не в адаптере.

Comment: Спасибо за советы. А при разрушении класса разве не уничтожается этот HashMap (ну когда фрагмент смениться)?

Comment: Уничтожается, но память обычно не возвращается до прохода GC. И смена фрагмента - это далеко не всегда уничтожение объекта. Нужна ещё инфа, что в "...", и память лучше снимать после выполнения GC (в DDMS кнопка есть "cause GC")

Comment: Спасибо проблема с ViewHolder исчезла. "что в "..."" - могу выложит код но там большой. Мне кажется что GC это хуже чем в плюсах самостоятельно следить - и нет проблем :). Получается в java тоже нужно чистить обьекты но деструктора нет. Или писать таким образом учитывая приколы с GC? Нужно эту тему изучить?

Comment: @KeyGenQt GC простой как двери - если нет ни одной жесткой ссылки он удаляет, если хоть одна завалялась - не может удалить, отсюда и надо плясать. Memory Analyzer как раз может показать кто держит ссылку.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос по сути решился, но чтоб он не возникал в дальнейшем изучите видео с Google I/O 2011 - [Memory management for Android Apps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk)

Там показаны типичные ситуация утечек памяти, и даны рекомендации как их обнаружить, понять причины и устранить.

Немного [на ту же тему на русском](http://habrahabr.ru/company/sebbia/blog/243537/)